# Can useHistory can be used as a value of useRef？

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

On a whim...
I wrote down the following code

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

// Parent component
const Example: React.FC = () => {
  // Case A:
  const packHistoryToRef = useRef<ReturnType<typeof useHistory>>(useHistory());

  // Case B:
  const history = useHistory();
  

  console.log(packHistoryToRef);    //  It works！
  
  return (
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(i => (
      // Case A solution
      <Child history={packHistoryToRef} />

      // Case B solution
      <Child history={history} /> 
    ))
  )
}


// Child component
const Child = ({ history }) => {
  // Case A: Is `history` object point to the same memory address？

  // Case B: There’s five printouts here. Does that mean it’s gonna repeat it five times？
  console.log(history, 'history')
}
```

**Is it safe for me to use like this？**

Otherwise, I think this is the benefit of doing this is

1. Save memory
2. Clear
3. It is very useful in child components (especially in ListItem)

Comment: 1) No 2) No 3) No. Can you show more of your intended use case where only `useHistory()` doesn't work?

Comment: @Bergi The code on the upper side is effective, I didn't find an example of not working ...

Comment: Sure, it's working, but it seems absolutely unnecessary. The first two points you mentioned are not true (it's worse in memory consumption and clarity than only doing `const history = useHistory()` without any refs), and I don't understand your third point. Can you elaborate? Maybe show how you'd use `packHistoryToRef` in this component and child components?

Comment: Ha.. Just like TodoList, But in child, I wanna jump to another page, But I felt it would be a waste to declare it in a child component, so I thought of using useRef in the parent component and distributing it as props to the child component ：）

Comment: Still - just distribute the `history` object as a prop, not a ref object!

Comment: Serious, I'm not sure. so I thought of this weird approach 

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*There’s five printouts here. Does that mean it’s gonna repeat it five times?*". If you render the `<Child>` component five times, that's the log I would expect. It would log the same history object five times.

Comment: OHHHH, I see, it doesn’t repeat `history` five times, they all point to the same memory address @Bergi

Comment: To Bergi's point, you likely have only a single router proving any routing context, which should also be providing only one history object. The `useHistory` hook is exposing this single history object so there's not much value in saving it in a ref of your own to pass around when you can just pass the history object directly, or use the `useHistory` hook in any children components that need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can useHistory can be used as a value of useRef

Yes, you can store *any* value you like into a React ref.

The reason `useRef(useHistory())` works is because it still follows the rules of hooks.

It would be equivalent to:

```
const history = useHistory();
const packHistoryToRef = useRef(history);
```

The hooks are called in the same order, unconditionally, each render cycle.

Does it

1. Save memory

   I suppose it saves a single variable declaration. Not much more.
2. Clear

   It seems clear enough to me, or anyone else familiar with javascript, React, and React hooks. Though generally it is better to be more explicit with what your code is doing than trying to be "fancy".
3. It is very useful in child components (especially in ListItem)

   I wouldn't say it's any more useful than just explicitly declaring the `history` object first.

I would suggest sticking to writing code that is more clearly read, each line with a specific purpose.

```
const history = useHistory();       // (1) define history
const historyRef = useRef(history); // (2) save ref
```

### Update

> ```
> // Parent component
> const Example: React.FC = () => {
>   // Case A:
>   const packHistoryToRef = useRef<ReturnType<typeof useHistory>>(useHistory());
>
>   // Case B:
>   const history = useHistory();
>   
>
>   console.log(packHistoryToRef);    //  It works！
>   
>   return (
>     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(i => (
>       // Case A solution
>       <Child history={packHistoryToRef} />
>
>       // Case B solution
>       <Child history={history} /> 
>     ))
>   )
> }
> ```

As I pointed out in comments, the `history` object provided by the `useHistory` hook is basically already a reference to a singular history instance, so storing it in a React ref of your own doesn't provide any additional benefit. Just pass down `history` from `useHistory` to children components.

Comment: I thought I was familiar with React and hooks, but it's not clear to me what usage `packHistoryToRef` has

Comment: @Bergi I suppose you have a point about *that* variable name, but I understood the question about being "clear" to be about the usage of storing the history object in a React ref, albeit abbreviated. I'd probably call it `historyRef`.

Comment: Oh, sure, I didn't even care about the variable name or calling a hook right as an argument of another hook - that is indeed clear. I was questioning the utility of the construct of putting a history object in a ref.

Comment: @Bergi Ah, touche, I don't know why one would do that, but *if* they did, then the code OP has is valid.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, as you say, （1）to define; （2） to save ref